# How to change textbox background color on getFocus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to change the background of my textbox in a WPF application on the getFocus event.  In winforms I did something like this and it worked fine.

```
    class Format_GUI
        {
            public void center_groupbox(Control cntrl, Form ms_form)
              {
                cntrl.Left = (ms_form.ClientSize.Width - cntrl.Width) / 2;

              }


           public void color_control(Control myControl)
              {
                Control inst_Control = new Control();
                inst_Control = myControl;
                inst_Control.BackColor =   System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E55451");
              }
```

}

I could then call the class function on the Enter event like this:

```
    private void txtTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGUI.highlight_SelectedControl(txtTextBox1);
    }
```

This works fine in WinForms.  Does anyone has an idea how this can be done in WPF apps?

Answer (score 1):

First, `TextBox` has a `GotFocus` event. Using an `x:Name` directive to make the box accessible from code...

In xaml...

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" GotFocus="Handler"/>
```

and then in code-behind...

```
private void Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    TextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(...));
}
```

However, in WPF, there is also the option of using a `Binding`

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E55451"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

This will cause not only the colorization behaviour, but also revert it when not focused, and without needing to rely on events, so the same code can be applied to any kind of Control

As with any style, this could also be placed in a resource dictionary to be used, possibly attaching to the type itself.

```
<!-- Resources under App.xaml. This can also be embedded in a ResourceDictionary -->
<Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="Control">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E55451"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
<Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well for me.  However, if there are many textboxes on my form, is there a way to have this done for all of them without having to write code for each one?

Comment: Yes, and this is the beauty of styles! I'll integrate it into my answer.

Note that @pikciu also had a great answer which simplifies the DataTriggers down to Triggers, which I was not aware of as possible. I advise you use his code for the style itself.

Answer (score 1):

Imho best way is to use triggers in XAML

```
<TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsFocused"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Background"
                                Value="#E55451" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your TextBox element in the XAML and add the GotFocus event.
This will assign a new handler in the code behind.
You have to cast the sender first, then you have access to the TextBox.

```
private void txtTextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbox = sender as TextBox;
    tbox.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

There is also a LostFocus event if you want to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this in your focused event to change it to that Hash Code

```
((TextBox)sender).Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#E55451"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find element in XAML and add events, i.e.:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120" GotFocus="textBox1_GotFocus" LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus" />
```

And set colors:

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}

private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
}
```